# Jquery and JS works onDOM not onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly let me start off by saying i dont have much knowledge on javascript and especially JQuery

I am having some issue with some javascript and Jquery loading on my page.

1) I have created some code here on JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gilera/mT9pV/1/, There is some javascript for the timezone converter and the JQuery function for the sliding of the hide/show div.

The code runs fine when using jsfiddle onDomready and displays both the time and the sliding of the hidden div works. But when using onLoad the hidden div works but not timezone converter. Any idea how i can get both to run when using onload mode on js fiddle?

2) Also if i compile the code and test website in browser i get the opposite that the Times load but not the hidden divs when clicking on them. how can i then maybe change the chan2.js script to run maybe as onDomready or do i need to add a script above the  to find the Jquery Libary?

I apologise for the lengthy post with te code but this is all new to me and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code im using

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>

<div class="schedule"><div class="event"><ul class="guides"><li class="icon"><img src="" alt="" width="26" height="27" class="icon"/></li><li class="time"><span data-utc="9:05"></span></li><li class="game">Team A vs Team B</li></ul></div><div class="place"><ul class="venue"><li class="field">Field A</li></ul></div></div>

<div class="schedule"><div class="event"><ul class="guides"><li class="icon"><img src="" alt="" width="26" height="27" class="icon"/></li><li class="time"><span data-utc="9:05"></span></li><li class="game">player A vs Player B</li></ul></div><div class="place"><ul class="venue"><li class="field">Court 3</li></ul></div></div>

<div id='out'></div>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='times2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='chans2.js'></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS style2.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
.event {
width: 600px;
height: 38px
}

.place{
display: none;
width: 590px;
height: 38px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #EB1D2D;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

ul.guides {
width: 570px;
height: 34px;
list-style: none;
display: block;
background-color: #D1E5FD;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-spacing: 5px;
padding-top:1px;
border-radius:5px
}
ul.guides a, ul.guides a:visted, ul.guides a:link {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #8090AB;
color: black;
}
ul.guides a:hover, ul.guides a:active, ul.guides a:focus {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li.icon {

display: inline-block;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
padding-left: 10px;

}
img.icon{
display:inline-block;
padding-top:3px;
}
li.time{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
width: 70px;
padding-left: 5px;
color: #0000FF;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;


}
li.game{
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #D1E5FD;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul.guides a, ul.nav a:visted{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #8090AB;
color: #000;
}

ul.guides a:hover, ul.guides a:active, ul.guides a:focus{
background-color: #6F7D94;
color: #000;
}

ul.venue {
width: 550px;
height: 34px;
list-style: none;
display: block;
background-color: #D1E5FD;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-spacing: 5px;
padding-top:1px;
border-radius:5px
}

li.field{
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #D1E5FD;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Javascript times.js

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
DisplayTimes();
}

function DisplayTimes(){
//legal formats: 1/10-13:00 for date and time
//             : 13:00 for time - presumes utc date is same as local date
var dd = new Date();
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var mon, date, hr, min;
for (var i=0 ; i<list.length ; i++){
if (list[i].hasAttribute('data-utc')){
var str = list[i].getAttribute('data-utc');
if(str.indexOf('/') < 0){
mon = dd.getMonth()+1;
date = dd.getDate();
hr = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(':'));
}else{
mon = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('/'));
date = str.substring(str.indexOf('/')+1,str.indexOf('-'));
hr = str.substring(str.indexOf('-')+1,str.indexOf(':'));
}

min = str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1);

dd.setUTCDate(mon);//date of month
dd.setUTCHours(hr); //24hour hour
dd.setUTCMinutes(min); //minutes
dd.setUTCSeconds(0); //seconds

var h = leadzero( dd.getHours() ); 
var m = leadzero( dd.getMinutes() );
var s = leadzero( dd.getSeconds() );

list[i].innerHTML += ' '+ h +':'+ m;
}
}
}

function leadzero(n){
var str1 = n.toString();
if(str1.length < 2){
str1 = '0'+ str1;
}
return str1;
}
```

Jquery chans2.js

```
$(".event").click(function(){
   //hide all rrshow
   $(".place").hide();

   //show only required rrshow
   $(this).parent().find(".place").show();
});
```

Thank you

EDIT: Sorry posted wrong code, Have changed chan2.js to what im using

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

In `times.js`,
instead of the code

```
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    DisplayTimes();
}
```

use

```
$(function(){
     DisplayTimes();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i posted wrong code there for chan2.js.. have edited the original post with the code im using.  I have tried adding that to the chan2.js but doesnt change anything. also tried adding it onto the time2.js

Comment: Changed the times2.js code as you said. When page loads live on server there is no times or hidden div working now

Answer (score 0):

Your css had issues, your html body elements were placed outside the <body></body> tags, and I changed everything to load within a single function passed to $(document).ready().  The following worked in my browser:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>onLoad</title>
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


</head>

<body>
<div class="schedule">
    <div class="event">
        <ul class="guides">
            <li class="icon"><img src="" alt="" width="26" height="27" class="icon"/></li>
            <li class="time"><span data-utc="9:05"></span></li>
            <li class="game">Team A vs Team B</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="place">
        <ul class="venue">
            <li class="field">Field A</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="schedule">
    <div class="event">
        <ul class="guides">
            <li class="icon"><img src="" alt="" width="26" height="27" class="icon"/></li>
            <li class="time"><span data-utc="9:05"></span></li>
            <li class="game">player A vs Player B</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="place">
        <ul class="venue">
            <li class="field">Court 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='out'></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='onLoad.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".event").click(function () {
        //hide all rrshow
        $(".place").hide();

        //show only required rrshow
        $(this).parent().find(".place").show();
    });

    function DisplayTimes() {
        //legal formats: 1/10-13:00 for date and time
        //             : 13:00 for time - presumes utc date is same as local date
        var dd = new Date();
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        var mon, date, hr, min;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].hasAttribute('data-utc')) {
                var str = list[i].getAttribute('data-utc');
                if (str.indexOf('/') < 0) {
                    mon = dd.getMonth() + 1;
                    date = dd.getDate();
                    hr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(':'));
                } else {
                    mon = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('/'));
                    date = str.substring(str.indexOf('/') + 1, str.indexOf('-'));
                    hr = str.substring(str.indexOf('-') + 1, str.indexOf(':'));
                }

                min = str.substring(str.indexOf(':') + 1);

                dd.setUTCDate(mon); //date of month
                dd.setUTCHours(hr); //24hour hour
                dd.setUTCMinutes(+min); //minutes
                dd.setUTCSeconds(0); //seconds

                var h = leadzero(dd.getHours());
                var m = leadzero(dd.getMinutes());
                var s = leadzero(dd.getSeconds());

                list[i].innerHTML += ' ' + h + ':' + m;
            }
        }
    }

    function leadzero(n) {
        var str1 = n.toString();
        if (str1.length < 2) {
            str1 = '0' + str1;
        }
        return str1;
    }

    DisplayTimes();
});
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
.event {
    width: 600px;
    height: 38px
}

.place{
    display: none;
    width: 590px;
    height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EB1D2D;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

ul.guides {
    width: 570px;
    height: 34px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #D1E5FD;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    padding-top:1px;
    border-radius:5px
}
ul.guides a, ul.guides a:visited, ul.guides a:link {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #8090AB;
    color: black;
}
ul.guides a:hover, ul.guides a:active, ul.guides a:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

li.icon {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
img.icon{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:3px;
}
li.time{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 70px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;


}
li.game{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #D1E5FD;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.guides a, ul.nav a:visited{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #8090AB;
    color: #000;
}

ul.guides a:hover, ul.guides a:active, ul.guides a:focus{
    background-color: #6F7D94;
    color: #000;
}

ul.venue {
    width: 550px;
    height: 34px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #D1E5FD;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    padding-top:1px;
    border-radius:5px
}

li.field{
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #D1E5FD;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/X5SVp/)

Comment: I see it works as nowrap -in <body> and onDomready.. But then how would i enter the code in the site so it runs as onDomready or as nowrap - in <body>? You will see if you compile the source code and run the site that it does not show the hidden div and only shows the time

Comment: @user2897821 I updated the answer above to address your comment above

Comment: @user2897821 I completely redid my answer better and checked it in my browser directly on my home pc without a fiddle.  Seems to work now.  You had a lot of issues with your code and I fixed the most direct ones.